# Unable to start Solr with Zookeeker Kerberos Cluster - bootstrap_confdir must be a directory

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, hortonworks-data-platform, solrcloud

I have configure Solr cluster pointing to Zookeeper with Kerberos authentication , everything looks good but while starting solr service i am getting below exception in logs.

```
2017-09-05 17:09:39.015 INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.c.Overseer Overseer (id=2427206981745377 solrHost:8983_solr-n_0000000021) starting
2017-09-05 17:09:39.093 INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.c.ZkController Register node as live in ZooKeeper:/live_nodes/solrHost:8983_solr
2017-09-05 17:09:39.098 ERROR (main) [   ] o.a.s.s.SolrDispatchFilter Could not start Solr. Check solr/home property and the logs
2017-09-05 17:09:39.099 INFO  (OverseerStateUpdate-242720698174537786-hostname:8983_solr-n_0000000021) [   ] o.a.s.c.c.ZkStateReader Updated live nodes from ZooKeeper... (0) -> (1)
2017-09-05 17:09:39.114 ERROR (main) [   ] o.a.s.c.SolrCore null:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bootstrap_confdir must be a directory of configuration files
    at org.apache.solr.core.ZkContainer.initZooKeeper(ZkContainer.java:137)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:477)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.createCoreContainer(SolrDispatchFilter.java:237)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.initialize(FilterHolder.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:873)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1404)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:561)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1516)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1441)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:75)

2017-09-05 17:09:39.134 INFO  (main) [   ] o.e.j.s.Server Started @11359ms
```

I am certainly not sure at this moment where should I define bootstrap_confdir ?

What could be possible reason for this exception ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some improper collection present in cluster after deleting that it worked.